# What happens to variable x in this for loop in C?

Tags: c, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation, static-memory-allocation

In this code below

```
int main(){
int i;
for(i = 0;i<4;i++){
int x = 1;
x++;
} // for close
}// main close
```

Here the variable `x` is `auto  storage class, right?

So, will the variable `x` get created, I mean memory allocation happens when the statement is encountered and gets destroyed when it reaches the end of the loop and gets created/memory is allocated again for `x`?

I tried to print the address of `x` in the loop and it prints the same address for `x` every time.So,does it mean every time x is created and destroyed and it is using the same room/memory block for it ?

If it is creating and destroying like that, doesn't it effect CPU usage?
If so, is there any way to prevent it and maintain good memory health?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is "nothing". Any optimizing compiler will optimize this variable out, because it is never read.

Even when you turn off the optimizer, the variable would be allocated once upon entering the function, and then set to 1 in each iteration, followed by an increment.

The allocation is very cheap, because it is in the automatic storage. The space is decided at compile time, so at run-time it costs you nothing. All iterations reuse the same location, so there will be no additional costs due to iterating.

Comment: optimizer means...do u mean volatile keyword and what do u mean by its never read !!!!?!?! Thanks in advance

Comment: @Curiousboy optimizer is the last stage of the compiler, when it figures out if instructions can be reordered or deleted in order to make code run faster. By "never read" i mean that there is no printing or other expressions that use x value.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the variable is constructed and destroyed for each turn in the loop.

However, as you have noticed, the compiler is smart enough to reuse the same storage for the variable each time. Likely on the stack, where the space could be allocated already when the function is entered. So there is no need to worry about the "memory management".

And if you turn on some optimizations, the compiler will also probably notice that none of the variables are really used for anything, and remove all of the code.

Answer (score 1):

It is implementation dependent. You see same memory address because compiler decided to do so. Memory isn't magically allocating at new address before each iteration. Automatic storage in the `x86` architecture is implemented using stack, allocation is done just by subtraction of `ESP`/`RSP` (x86/x64) register, which points to the top of the stack. You can read articles about it in the internet.

Compiler just reassign memory every iteration (not allocating/deallocating)

This is assembly listing of your code (GCC 6.3, x86). Comment in the assembly language starts with `;`. I added c like pseudocode to explain the meaning of instructions

```
main:
        push    ebp
        mov     ebp, esp ; Create new stack frame
        sub     esp, 16 ; Allocate memory for local variables
        mov     DWORD PTR [ebp-4], 0 ; i = 0;
.L3:
        cmp     DWORD PTR [ebp-4], 3  ; if(i > 3)
                                      ; {
        jg      .L2                   ;    break;
                                      ; }
        mov     DWORD PTR [ebp-8], 1 ; x = 1;
        add     DWORD PTR [ebp-8], 1 ; x += 1;
        add     DWORD PTR [ebp-4], 1 ; i += 1;
        jmp     .L3 ; Go to location .L3
.L2:
        mov     eax, 0 ; Set return value to 0
        leave ; Restore the stack pointer
        ret ; Return to the caller
```

So address of `ebp - 8` (or `int x`) will be same every time.

This is optimized code assembly listing (GCC 6.3,֊O3, x86).

```
main:
        xor     eax, eax ; Set return value to 0
        ret ; Return to the caller
```

Answer (score 0):

In each iteration of the for loop, you are creating the variable 'x,' setting it to 1, and incrementing it to 2.  'x' is being destroyed because it only exists within the for loop.  If you don't want it to be created and destroyed each iteration, you could simply declare it above the for loop.

What exactly are you trying to accomplish with this code, though?  It doesn't seem to be doing much.  Also, since you're worried about memory allocation, the variable 'i' could just be declared in the for loop so that you don't have it hanging around after you're done with the for loop.

Comment: Hi @Silamoth,destroyed in the sense....after exiting the loop or in each iteration ?

Comment: After each iteration, it's destroyed.  In other words, it will be created and destroyed 4 times.  However, as someone else said, a smart, modern compiler will end up reusing the variable and its location since it's being recreated every iteration.